# Celery. Why my task work ONLY if I run this manualy in shell(manage.py shell)?

Tags: django, django-celery

```
>>> from app.tasks import SendSomething
>>> eager_result = SendSomething().apply()
```

Why my task work ONLY if I run this manualy in shell(manage.py shell)?

settings.py

```
from datetime import timedelta
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {'send-something':
                       {'task': 'app.tasks.SendSomething',
                        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=300),
                        }}
```

I run:

> python manage.py celeryd

and I have:

> ```
> [Tasks]
>   . app.tasks.SendSomething
> ```

```
[2013-05-01 18:44:22,895: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@aaa ready.
```

but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`celeryd` is the worker process. By default it does not schedule the periodic tasks. You can either run with the `-B` option to run the beat process along with the worker

> python manage.py celeryd -B

or you can run an additional `celerybeat` process

> python manage.py celerybeat

See http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler